# Is there a way to use matlabs inputparser to use the default value when non valid data is entered?

Tags: matlab, validation

So I am trying to add an input parser to a few files in matlab. All of the parameters have a default value and for this specific case there has to be 2 optional positional parameters and then the rest are truly optional. This is the code that I have for the input parser that does correctly validate the input but I need something that if I pass an empty string or a  null in the parser would just use the default option. What would be the "best" way of going about this?

```
p = inputParser;
validStrings = {'one', 'two', 'three'};
defaultString = 'none';
checkString = @(x) (any(validatestring(x,validStrings));

addOptional(p,'number',defaultString, @checkString);
```

when passing an empty string into this it just errors out saying that '' is not an expected option.

Comment: If `''` and null are valid strings then they should be added as such to the parser and cleaned after the fact. Or you clean your data before you pass it to the parser.

Comment: I suggest you take a look at [this related question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/39946990/3372061), and specifically [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40004496/3372061). Long story short: `inputParser` with optional arguments that are allowed to be character arrays might lead to unexpected results.